# "Firmware progress error" reported by blade in IBM BladeCenter S

Tags: ibm, firmware, bladecenter

I have a BladeCenter S with three blades installed. Two of my LS21 blades are reporting the following error in the web-based Advanced Management Module:

> **(12/20/13 10:49:19) (LS21 2 Core 2K8) Firmware progress error**
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> The service processor for the specified blade server has detected a system firmware error. The firmware will not be loaded.
>
> **User Response:**
>
> Refer to the Problem Determination and Service Guide for the specified blade server to determine the device-specific actions to resolve this event. The Problem Determination and Service Guide is available on the Web.
>
> If you do not have access to the Problem Determination and Service Guide, perform these steps:
>
> - Reboot the blade server.
> - Update the service processor firmware for the blade server through the advanced management module Web interface. Select Blade Tasks and then Firmware Update.
> - Reseat the blade server.
> - Update the system firmware for the blade server.
> - Replace the system board (trained service technician only).

I tried the first step, rebooting, but this didn't seem to help. Note that when I connect my KVM to that particular blade, I see *nothing* when I boot. Not even the BIOS screens one normally expects to see in a booting computer.

I'm stuck on the second step. I downloaded the correct firmware from the IBM website, which was delivered as an executable file. The executable allows you to either:

- extract the firmware files to disk; or
- create a floppy disk to try and boot from.

I tried the first option, and it spat out three files: `FULLFW.MOT`, `wflash.exe` and `wflash64.exe`. I tried loading the `FULLFW.MOT` using the web-based Advanced Management Module, but it told me the format was incorrect.

I then tried option two (*incidentally, just try finding a floppy disk in 2013*), but this didn't work either. I plugged the IBM USB-attached diskette drive into the Blade Centre and power-cycled the blade, but nothing happened.

I'm at rather a loss of how to continue now. Any suggestions?